# Create view and make SUM of column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view

I have two tables (A and B) in SQL Server. I want to create a view with an union or dissolve on NameA, with the sum of count and with the geometry.

Result should be something like:

| nameC | ogr_geometry | SUM_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| main1 | GEOMETRY | 4 |
| main2 | GEOMETRY | 2 |
| main3 | GEOMETRY | 2 |

**tableA**

| nameA | Count |
| --- | --- |
| main1 | 1 |
| main1 | 1 |
| main1 | 1 |
| main1 | 1 |
| main3 | 1 |
| main3 | 1 |
| main2 | 1 |
| main2 | 1 |

**tableB**

| nameB | ogr_geometry |
| --- | --- |
| main1 | GEOMETRY |
| main2 | GEOMETRY |
| main3 | GEOMETRY |

I tried:

```
CREATE or ALTER VIEW SUM_main
AS 
    SELECT 
        SUM(Count) AS SUM_count,
        TableB.ogr_geometry
    FROM 
        TableA
    INNER JOIN 
        TableB ON TableA.nameA = TableB.nameB
    GROUP BY
        TableA.nameA
```

It doesn't work.

Works, but without geometry or the names, but seems to do the SUM:

```
CREATE or ALTER VIEW SUM_main
AS 
    SELECT SUM(Count) AS SUM_count
    FROM TableA
    INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.nameA = tableB.nameB
    GROUP by tableA.nameA
```

|  | SUM_count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |

How do I get the names and geometry?

Comment: `“invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause”` is kind of telling you the problem

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be an aggregation applied to the `ogr_geometry` column. Since it's not one of the GROUP BY columns, SQL is trying to aggregate it in some way across groups.

If `ogr_geometry` is comparable then you can do something like this:

```
SELECT tableA.nameA
    , SUM(count) AS count
    , MIN(tableB.ogr_geometry) AS geometry
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.nameA=tableB.nameB
GROUP by tableA.nameA
```

If not, because `ogr_geometry` is actually a geometry type, you will need to do the aggregation first on tableA and then join with tableB:

```
SELECT tableA.nameA
    , tableB.ogr_geometry
    , tableA.count
FROM (
    SELECT nameA
        , SUM(count) AS count
    FROM tableA
    GROUP BY nameA
) tableA
INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.nameA=tableB.nameB
```

Comment: This gives me "Operand data type geometry is invalid for min operator."

Comment: See updated answer, it wasn't clear from your original question the types you were working with, but that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Non-agrregated columns in `SELECT` must be the same or subset of the `GROUP BY` columns. As Geometry type is not comparable, it can not be among `GROUP BY` columns. Do it in two steps

```
SELECT ta.*, TableB.ogr_geometry
FROM (
     SELECT nameA, SUM(Count) AS SUM_count
     FROM TableA
     GROUP BY nameA ) ta
INNER JOIN tableB ON ta.nameA = tableB.nameB
```

Comment: This gives me "The type "geometry" is not comparable. It cannot be used in the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: Provide  CREATE TABLE to make datatypes visible for community. See edited answer.